# reading selected data from multiple files

Tags: fortran

I need some technical help in modifying my FORTRAN coding. I have searched the Internet but I can't fine one which can solve my need.

Basically I am analyzing simulation data using FORTRAN program. Firstly, I shall explain the format of my data to make easy the understanding of what I want. I have 10 files. Each file contains x, y z, data for 1000 frames and each frame contains 20736 (x,y,z) data. Since the total size of all data is about 10 GB for all 10,000 frames, I have to break them into small chunks (10 files) to avoid any crash during calculation. At the beginning of each file (first line) there is a text which can be neglected and each frame ending with information of the box size (bx,by,bz). This is the format of my data files.

I have attached the coding which I have been using for analysis.

The current codding will do calculation file after file and frame after frame in the sequential order. But now I want to do the calculation on selected frames only by jumping frame after frame with certain pattern. For example, I choose frame 1, 4, 8, 12, 16.... and so on until the last frame (10,000).

I have no idea how to choose the frames which are more then 1000 which fall in the second or third files.

I have shown my code below:

---

```
module all_parameter
integer,parameter :: MAXATOM=20736
integer,parameter :: nat = 20736                    
integer, parameter :: startFiles=31
integer, parameter :: endFiles=40
integer,parameter :: NO_OF_FILES=10
integer,parameter :: FRAMES_IN=1000
integer, parameter :: totalFrames = ( NO_OF_FILES * FRAMES_IN )
integer :: i, j, k, IFram, nhb, nlipid, jjj
integer :: BIN, iat, jat
!real :: DELR, fnid, GNRM, RCUT, rlower, rupper
real :: junk, dR, bx, by, bz, bbx
real :: only_head, only_tail, only_water
real :: mass_head, mass_tail, mass_water
character*4 at(MAXATOM)
real,dimension(MAXATOM) :: x, y, z
real,dimension(3) :: rcm
real,dimension(MAXATOM) :: rx, ry, rz 
real,dimension(MAXATOM) :: mass

integer, parameter :: startlipid=1
integer, parameter :: endlipid=64
integer, parameter :: lipidNo=64

real, parameter :: PI = (22.0/7.0)
real, dimension(startlipid:endlipid) :: array_UniVekLx, array_UniVekLy, array_UniVekLz
integer ::  no, no2, c71, c72, c80, c81
real        ::  p1x, p1y, p1z, p2x, p2y, p2z, vekx, veky, vekz
real        ::  mag_vekp1p2,  unit_vekx, unit_veky, unit_vekz
real        ::  sum_UniVekLx, sum_UniVekLy, sum_UniVekLz
real        ::  avg_frame_vekx, avg_frame_veky, avg_frame_vekz
real        ::  xx, yy, zz, frame_MagLipVek, theta,theta2, uni_frame_Vekx, uni_frame_Veky, uni_frame_Vekz
real        ::  xxx, yyy, zzz,UniVekLx, UniVekLy, UniVekLz, FrameAvgUniVekMag
real        ::  avg_UniVekLx, avg_UniVekLy,avg_UniVekLz, MagLipVek

end module all_parameter



PROGRAM order_parameter
use all_parameter
implicit none
!=========================================================================
! Open files to be read and to write on
!=========================================================================
!
    ! Topology file     !CHANGE

open(unit=31,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set1.traj ")
open(unit=32,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set2.traj ")
open(unit=33,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set3.traj ")
open(unit=34,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set4.traj ")
open(unit=35,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set5.traj ")
open(unit=36,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set6.traj ")
open(unit=37,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set7.traj ")
open(unit=38,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set8.traj ")
open(unit=39,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set9.traj ")
open(unit=40,status="old",file="../malto_thermoNEW_Ori_50ns-set10.traj ")

! Open New Files
open(unit=51,status="unknown",file="BOXinfo.dat ")
open(unit=75,status="unknown",file="magnitude_theta_lipid-thermo-malto.dat")

do k = startlipid, endlipid
array_UniVekLx(k) =0.0
array_UniVekLy(k) =0.0
array_UniVekLz(k) =0.0
end  do


 ! READ COORDINATES IN FRAMES FROM TRAJ file

INPUTFILES: do jjj = startFiles, endFiles
! LOOP OVER FRAMES
IFram = 1
read(jjj,'(a)') junk

!&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
        !IFram = 1
WHOLE: do while ( IFram <= FRAMES_IN)   
read(jjj,'(10F8.3)') (x(i),y(i),z(i),i = 1,nat)  ! reading TRAJ file 

        read(jjj,'(3F8.3)') bx,by,bz   
        write(51,'(a,3F8.3)') 'BOXINFO', bx,by,bz


        ! LOOP OVER ATOMS

        loop1: do j = startlipid, endlipid !nat in lipids
            loop2: do i = 45, 45 !,3    !atoms in a lipid

                no= i + (j-1)*81
                !no2= (no + 18)

                c71=no
                c72=(no+3)
                    p1x=((x(c71) + x(c72))/2.0 )
                    p1y=((y(c71) + y(c72))/2.0 )
                    p1z=((z(c71) + z(c72))/2.0 )
                    .       
                    .
                    .
                    .

            enddo loop2 ! going to next lipid
        !CLOSE LOOP OVER ATOMS
        enddo loop1  ! going to next frame , before that



!CLOSE LOOP OVER A FRAME
IFram = IFram + 1

enddo WHOLE


!CLOSE LOOP OVER ALL FILES
  enddo INPUTFILES

 end program order_parameter
```

---

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the loop, unless `mod(framenumber, 4) == 0` skip to the next iteration (the CYCLE statement does that in Fortran). That way, you'll process only every fourth frame.

Also, you way want to use a somewhat more precise value for PI. 22/7, WTF?

Comment: I like to use real(8),parameter::pi=datan(1.0d0)*4.0d0

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the program needs to know which file it is reading, 1, 2... 10.  Call that ifile.  Then the frame with the file, say frame_in_file.  Then you have frame =  (ifile-1) * frame_in_file.    Do you have a rule to decide whether you want to process "frame"?    If the rule is to process every fourth, use mod and cycle as suggested @janneb.   Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking.

With ten files, it would be easier to write the filename to a string and process them with a loop, opening each file in turn with the same unit number and closing at the end of the loop.   This would be a little easier if you used the convention that the number in the file name was always two digits, with a leading zero if less than 10:

```
do ifile=1, 10
   write (filename, '( "myfile_number", I2.2, ".data" )' ) ifile
   open (unit=30, file=filename, ...)
   loop: read from the file...
      calculate overall frame number ...
      cycle out of read loop if unsuitable frame...
      process the frame...
   end read loop
   close (unit=30)
end do
```

Comment: Wrt the file name, nowadays most compilers support the I0 edit descriptor, making it easy to construct a file name without leading zeros.

Comment: True. But then you would break lexical sorting, so it might not be such a good idea. Directory listings would come out in the order 1, 10, 2, 3, etc.